# Analyze Stock Market Bottom Timing without Looping over Data Frame Rows

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am replicating this [blog post](https://ofdollarsanddata.com/why-market-timing-can-be-so-appealing/) in Python.
The blog post shows that even if you know future stock market bottoms, only buying stocks when the stock market is below future stock market bottoms provides only a modest edge of 22%.

The code below replicates the blog post's result (approximately, I use different data).
However, in cell `# In[8]`, it loops over the rows in data frame `df`.
This loop makes the logic clear (if the stock market is below the future stock market bottom, move cash to equity, else invest cash in Treasuries and maintain equity investment) but seems un-Pythonic (and like code I would have written in my high school Basic class 25 years ago).

In cell `# In[8]`, can I avoid looping over rows?

Note, that I wrote this code in a Jupyter Notebook, and `display()` requires a Jupyter Notebook.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr


# In[2]:


url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/%5EGSPC?period1=-1325635200&period2=1588118400&interval=1d&events=history'
gspc = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
display(gspc)


# In[3]:


url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/VFINX?period1=315619200&period2=1588118400&interval=1d&events=history'
vfinx = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
vfinx['Return'] = vfinx['Adj Close'].pct_change()
display(vfinx)


# In[4]:


dgs3mo = pdr.get_data_fred('DGS3MO', start=vfinx.index.min())
display(dgs3mo)


# In[5]:


df = gspc[['Close']].join(vfinx[['Return']]).join(dgs3mo / 100 / 365).dropna()
df.columns = ['SP500', 'RM', 'RF']
display(df)


# In[6]:


df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
df['SP500_Fwd_Min'] = df.SP500.cummin()
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
display(df)


# In[7]:


df['To_Equity'] = np.where(df.SP500 <= df.SP500_Fwd_Min, 1, 0)
df['Smart_Cash'] = 0.
df['Smart_Equity'] = 0.
df['Dumb'] = 0.
df['Daily'] = 1


# In[8]:


for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    if (df.To_Equity[i - 1] == 1):
        df.Smart_Equity[i] = (df.Smart_Equity[i-1] + df.Smart_Cash[i-1] + df.Daily[i-1]) * (1 + df.RM[i])
        df.Smart_Cash[i] = 0
    else:
        df.Smart_Equity[i] = (df.Smart_Equity[i-1]) * (1 + df.RM[i])
        df.Smart_Cash[i] = (df.Smart_Cash[i-1] + df.Daily[i-1]) * (1 + df.RF[i])

    df.Dumb[i] = (df.Dumb[i-1] + df.Daily[i-1]) * (1 + df.RM[i])

df['Smart'] = df.Smart_Equity + df.Smart_Cash      



# In[9]:


df[['Smart', 'Dumb']].plot(figsize=(12,8))


# In[10]:


np.log(df.Smart[-1]) - np.log(df.Dumb[-1])


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: `display` is not defined, it should be noted that a Jupyter instance is required.

Comment: Please modify your question title to indicate what you are doing, i.e. _Analyzing market bottom timings (?) from Yahoo (?)_ . Something to that effect.